# What purpose does the word "bien" serve in this context?

Tags: sens, expressions, adverbes, participe-passé

> « Vous voilà **bien partis** pour devenir chevaliers. »

I wonder if the "**bien**" is placed for emphasis purposes, with the entire sentence meaning:

> "Here you two are, finally **well** on your way to become knights."

Also, is the "**partis**" a Passé Composé form of the verb "partir", which serves as a kind of adjective in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right. It is an emphasis and also showing positivity of the upcoming action.

You can translate it as : "Here is a **good start** to become knight".

I think here the correct gramatical form is "participe passé".

Comment: `Here is a good start to become knight` translates more to `voilà/voici un bon départ pour devenir chevalier`, same overall meaning, but different.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is an emphasis and for example instead of saying " Merci beaucoup" you can say also "Merci bien"

Answer (score 1):

*Bien* here is an *adverb*. It precises the verb.

CNRTL says here: http://cnrtl.fr/definition/bien **so *well* is exactly that.**

> En rapport avec certains critères d'appréciation individuels ou
>   collectifs; d'une manière exactement adéquate à l'idée ou à l'effet
>   attendu(e), propre à recevoir l'approbation:

*partis* is OK. It is exactly a *participe passé*, You could say also:

> Nous sommes bien arrivés.
>
> Nous sommes très attendus.